# Encoding 64 bit number with hashid library

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, decoding, hashids

previously we use to generate 32 bit number for ids now we have started generating 64 bit number as ids. The problem we are facing is we used hashId library to encode the number but we are not able to encode the 64-bit number with this library it gives empty string if we encode 64-bit. Any walk around this? I cannot switch to other library as i still have 32-bit ids present. Changing library would create a lot of trouble.

64 bit ids:-
`191051377965797390`,`191059128930537487` 
Library is:- https://hashids.org/javascript/

Is it possible to encode 64bit using this library?

Comment: what do you use to represent/store 64 bit integers in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't store them as integers, Instead i represent it as a string of numbers as i don't need to do any mathematical operations with it.

Comment: strings are converted to numbers (plain `number`, not `BigInt`). they'll be "out-of-range" (see `Number.SAFE_MAX_INTEGER`). Fortunately it also supports `BigInt` but AFAIK you'll need to do the conversion yourself (just call ctor...)